# Sort by Value in Razor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, razor

```
 <ul class="related_forms_list">
    @foreach (var year in test.years ?? new List<YearsVM>())
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Test","Link", new { id=Year.Id })">@Year.Year</a></li>
        }
```

My code above pulls a list of years that is gathered from my database.  However, they aren't organized by year.  I was thinking Javascript would be the best way to do this but I am unsure of how to write the javascript so it affects my list.

Comment: You're already iterating using Razor, then why not simply `@foreach (var year in (test.years ?? new List<YearsVM>()).OrderBy(x => x.Year))`?

Comment: Also, what's the point of `?? new List<YearsVM>()` when you know the loop will never run when you're iterating over an empty list?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't doing the Order By because it was messing up the ?? new List. I took out the New list and added the OrderBy and it works great! please put your answer in the answers so I can give it the green checkmark of awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `OrderBy()` in Razor:

```
@foreach (var year in (test.years ?? new List<YearsVM>()).OrderBy(x => x.Year))
```

(By encapsulating `(test.years ?? new List<YearsVM>())` in its own brackets)

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)